# SFDC formula field to convert decimal number to hex string

Tags: formula-field

I'm looking to convert an auto-number field value to a hex string formula field.  My auto-number is not going to be larger than 999,999.  I found some suggestions on the net (thanks Chris Gary) and came up with this formula:

```
case(mod( floor(Decimal_Number__c/65536) ,16),0,"0",1,"1",2,"2",3,"3",4,"4",5,"5",6,"6",7,"7",8,"8",9,"9",10,"A",11,"B",12,"C",13,"D",14,"E",15,"F","")
&
case(mod( floor(Decimal_Number__c/4096) ,16),0,"0",1,"1",2,"2",3,"3",4,"4",5,"5",6,"6",7,"7",8,"8",9,"9",10,"A",11,"B",12,"C",13,"D",14,"E",15,"F","")
&
case(mod( floor(Decimal_Number__c/256) ,16),0,"0",1,"1",2,"2",3,"3",4,"4",5,"5",6,"6",7,"7",8,"8",9,"9",10,"A",11,"B",12,"C",13,"D",14,"E",15,"F","")
&
case(mod( floor(Decimal_Number__c/16) ,16),0,"0",1,"1",2,"2",3,"3",4,"4",5,"5",6,"6",7,"7",8,"8",9,"9",10,"A",11,"B",12,"C",13,"D",14,"E",15,"F","")
&
case(mod(Decimal_Number__c,16),0,"0",1,"1",2,"2",3,"3",4,"4",5,"5",6,"6",7,"7",8,"8",9,"9",10,"A",11,"B",12,"C",13,"D",14,"E",15,"F","")
```

A value of 999999 in my number field gives F423F in my hex string formula field. 
 I'm wondering if anyone has a better approach.

Comment: That's about as efficient a way as I can see.  I might spell the divisor out in terms of 16 -- 16^0, 16^1, 16^2, ... -- to make it clearer what's happening there, but that's just me being silly.

Comment: Putting it into play I found that my test formula here worked because field 'Decimal_Number__c' is a number field.  When I switched over to an auto-number field I had to use the value function:  case(mod( floor(value(autoNumberField__c)/65536) ,16), etc.

Answer (score 1):

With a formula field, I don't think you could do much better in terms of readability or compiled size.

You may be able to find a way to reduce some of the repetition, you could use `POW(16,<integer>)` to replace the `Decimal_Number__c/<x>` where x is 16, 256, 4096, 65536. Really, any changes you make to the formula here are going to be a trade-off between compile size, repetition, and readability/maintainability.